# C# WebBrowser: Extract tag value

Tags: c#, tags, browser, image

How can I extract a value of an "`<img>`" tag from a page that's loaded into WebBrowser? I don't want to wait for the whole page to get downloaded with all the images, I just want to get a particular image src from the page.
Thanks.

Comment: Whats a "" tag? Easiest would be to use the `HtmlAgilityPack` I think. Just Google it :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, He needs the html first to use `HtmlAgilityPack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we are talking about the WebBrowser control. You can use the event [`OnNavigated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx), according to MSDN:

> When the `Navigated` event occurs, the new document has begun loading,
>   which means you can access the loaded content through the `Document`,
>   `DocumentText`, and `DocumentStream` properties. Handle the
>   `DocumentCompleted` event to receive notification when the WebBrowser
>   control finishes loading the new document.

To parse html, take a look at [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). To get all `src`'s with it, here is an example from their codeplex site:

```
foreach(HtmlNode img in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img[@src"])
{
   HtmlAttribute att = img["src"];
}
```

`doc` is an `HtmlDocument`, check the constructor overloads for it.